# Пунктуация в ЕГЭ

Tags: пунктуация, егэ

Собственно, возникли вопросы по поводу знаков препинания в сочинении ЕГЭ: разрешены ли факультативные знаки препинания? авторская пунктуация? каких правил придерживается эксперт ФИПИ и каких на самом деле стоит придерживаться?

Допустим, будет написана апелляция на результаты ЕГЭ - какую доказательную базу (правил, уже решенных вопросов экспертами РАН или другими авторитетными лицами...) может использовать участник экзамена и какая будет действенной?